# Check if something exists in .net core database and return as boolean

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I'm trying to figure out how to check if something exists in my database. In this case what is happening is it's figuring out if the user has 'Liked' an image, and returning it as a true or false value. The way I'm doing it is to check if there is one version or more versions of this 'Like', if there is, return true, otherwise return false. This is the code.

What I'm currently doing:

```
    public bool checkCurrentUserLiked(int currentUserId, int imageId)
    {
        var hasData = _context.PhotoLikes.Where(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId);

        var dataToReturn = false;

        if (hasData.Count() >= 1)
        {
            // entity exists in database
            dataToReturn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dataToReturn = false;
            // nope
        }
        return dataToReturn;
    }
```

Another way that I tried

```
    public bool checkCurrentUserLiked(int currentUserId, int imageId)
    {
        bool hasData = _context.PhotoLikes.Any(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId);

        var dataToReturn = false;

        if (hasData)
        {
            // entity exists in database
            dataToReturn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dataToReturn = false;
            // nope
        }
        return dataToReturn;
    }
```

When i get to the :

if (hasData.Count() == 1), the error i get is:
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

and it doesn't run

[EDIT]

The error I'm getting here is : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'bool'

```
    public bool checkCurrentUserLiked(int currentUserId, int imageId)
    {
          _context.PhotoLikes.Any(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId);

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: if (hasData.Count() == 1), the error i get is: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Could you clarify "check if there is one version or more versions of this 'Like'" part? In the first example `if (hasData.Count() == 1)` will return false if you have more than one result which could be a potential bug. The second example `_context.PhotoLikes.Any(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId)` will return a `true` if more than one `PhotoLikes` match the given condition. You don't really have to store it in a separate variable.

Comment: Okay i've edited the question, it should me one or more. I've also edited the question based on what you've said but I'm getting another error

Comment: It sounds to me like you aren't generating a new DbContext for each request.   How is the db context configured in your startup.cs ?

Comment: As for your second error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'bool'", I wasnt able to recreate and im sure this was just a typo, but do you have a return before _context.PhotoLikes.Any(...)? I was able to rewrite your method working with an IQueryable<T> and it doesnt give an error.

Comment: @Neil, this is how it looks in startup.cs :           services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));                      and in the DataContext it looks like this :                                        public DbSet<PhotoLike> PhotoLikes { get; set; }

Comment: You are missing a return statement `return _context.PhotoLikes.Any(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId);
`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    public bool checkCurrentUserLiked(int currentUserId, int imageId)
        => _context.PhotoLikes.Any(x => x.LikerId == currentUserId && x.ImageId == imageId));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of the methods suggested but none of them worked, what I ended up doing was removing the function and rewriting it inside of the property that needed it.

This is what I mean:

'hasCurrentUserLiked' is what I was trying to work out. I didn't really make any major changes, I just changed the code around (not sure why this works, but it does)

```
            (f, p) => new FeedsForReturnDto
            {
                Id = f.feed.Id,
                PhotoUrl = f.feed.photoUrl,
                Username = f.feed.Username,
                Description = f.feed.Description,
                DateAdded = f.feed.DateAdded,
                IsImage = f.feed.IsImage,
                // v Is the thing we were trying to figure out
                hasCurrentUserLiked = _context.PhotoLikes.Any(x => x.LikerId == user.Id && x.ImageId == f.feed.Id),
                Likes = _context.PhotoLikes.Where(x => x.ImageId == f.feed.Id).Count()
            });
```